# How to create two pagination in Django for the same page?

Tags: django, listview, pagination

I have searching on the internet but I did not find a good answer, I would like to know if is possible to create multiple pagination with ListView, like I changed my context to return two list of different objects and then I will put each in a row and each row will have a paginatior for that list.
How should I proceed to achieve this ?

ListView

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['oportunities_idea'] = Oportunity.objects.filter(goal_oportunity_idea=True)
        context['oportunities_project'] = Oportunity.objects.filter(goal_oportunity_project=True)
        return context
```

index.html

```
<div class="row mt15"><!--project-->
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane row fade in active">   
        <legend>Projects</legend>                                                     
            {% for project in  oportunities_project %}                    
                <h2>{{project.title}}<h2>                    
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:1 %}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    </div>     
 </div>
<div class="row mt15">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane row fade in active">   
        <legend>Ideas</legend>                                                     
            {% for idea in  oportunities_idea %}                    
                <h2>{{idea.title}}<h2>                   
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:1 %}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    </div>     
 </div>
```

Comment: I can recommend this. This can solve your problem, info is in the docs here: https://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: thanks a lot that helped me.